# i can view photos of an account via instagram username?

Tags: api, photo, instagram

hi I wanted to know if you can see pictures of istagram by username by api..

I have a blog with the members and I wanted to if it was possible to do that through the username of instagram users shared the their pictures ..

how this site http://listagr.am although I do not think this is an officially ...

tnx for info :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> The OAuth 2.0 spec allows you to specify the scope of the access you’re requesting from the user.
>
> [...]
>
> **basic** - to read any and all data related to a user (e.g. following/followed-by lists, **photos**, etc.) (granted by default)

I haven't used the API, but it seems feasible to retrieve user photos (once you have granted access), popular photos (like the home of [listagr.am](http://listagr.am/), etc.

**Edit:** if you want to be capable of retrieving photos of any user whose username you known, sorry if I understood wrong, I don't have enough insight of the API.

Related [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/vLfi1TbodhY), from 2011.